# Transformer Designing

Tags: transformer, electric-machine

Why don't we keep low voltage winding of transformer at one loop and adjust the rest of the circuit accordingly? Like in clamp meters. 
Also is there any software where I can model unorthodox shapes for my transformer and simulate it's flux flow etc?

Comment: 1) Because it's daft idea and 2) this place isn't a shop or a magazine or a buyer's guide or a retail park or market.

Comment: Look up transformer saturation. Vt=NAB

Comment: Start working through maths, also there are papers that describe how to model hysteresis curves. You get to write your own software.

Comment: I find this question unclear since the context is missing. What is "the rest of the circuit" when you say it could be "adjusted accordingly"? Why exactly do you mention "clamp meters"?

Answer (score 5):

For any given core area and frequency, there is a maximum 'volts per turn'.

For a typical small (50VA, ish?) toroidal core I have to hand, the core is 25mm by 13mm. Iron saturates somewhere between 1.5T and 2T depending on the grade. If I run the core with the flux peaking at +/- 1.8T at 50Hz, I will generate about 170mV peak per turn. So a 12Vrms winding would need 100 turns, the 240v mains winding would need 2000.

It *is* possible to use a core large enough to get the voltage in a single turn. For instance, an iron core with an area of 0.032m, that is 0.13m by 0.25m, the size of a railway sleeper, would give you 12Vrms per turn at 50Hz, and a very heavy transformer.

As Sam points out, increasing the frequency increases the volts per turn proportionally. This is why aircraft use 400Hz AC, it reduces the weight of iron and copper in a transformer by an order of magnitude, and is about the highest frequency practical with iron laminations. Ferrite transformers used in SMPS tend to use frequencies in the 10s to 100s of kHz, and these *can* get away with one or a few turns.

Answer (score 2):

Because unless you're running the transformer at several MHz (at which point you really *can* have just one turn) or you want some small fraction of a volt (i.e. you're making a spot welder), you need the number of secondary vs primary turns to be equal to the voltage ratio between the primary and secondary and the number of primary turns is mainly dictated by the required inductance you need to prevent core saturation under normal conditions. At mains frequency you usually need primary inductances in the millihenry range, this pretty much means you need quite a few turns in the primary and unless your input voltage is super high/output voltage super low, you're pretty much guaranteed to need quite a few turns in your secondary to get to be right ratio. The only way around this is to use a super high permeability core (higher permeability = less turns for the same inductance) but many of those materials have other problems (like being flamin' expensive) that make for bad transformers.

Comment: High permeability decreases the magnetising current, you need higher saturation to increase the volts/turn. High primary inductance does not prevent core saturation, enough turns/volt does. I agree with your frequency comment however.